# Visualize stack for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a recursive call in node.js. I am trying to figure how to optimize it so it uses the lease CPU cycles and has the smallest stack memory.

```
function baz(callback) {

        if (bool){
            callback();
            return;
        }
        else{
            setImmediate(function(){
                return baz(callback);
            });
        }
}
```

The only thing I can really tweak is the presence of return statements and where to place them. I think the stack will grow more without returning in the right place.

Is there a profiling tool for node.js where I can see the stack during runtime?

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=node.js%20profiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By placing your call to `baz` inside `setImmediate` you aren't actually recursing down a call stack in the way you might think. The key point to realize is that your first call to baz will return *before* your second call to `baz` begins. (Note that in javascript functions the `return` keyword is optional, a function simply returns `undefined` by default once it reaches the end of the function block)

Or, think of it this way. Some event, call it event A, triggers the first call to `baz` and the beginning of your recursive routine. The callback you give to `setImmediate` will not start right away, it will be queued as a new event, call it event 'B', and this event won't start until *after* event A has finished, *after* execution has climbed back out of that event's call stack.

Node.js will continue resolivng any other events that might have been  scheduled in priority before your `setImmediate` was called, until it eventually gets to event 'B' and runs your second invocation of `baz`, and so on.

In other words, `baz` is an event driven algorithm, not a recursive one. Your stack depth won't grow arbitrarily large.

Comment: Whether `bool` is true or false, the return statement inside your `setImmediate` callback is returning `undefined`. It's worth noting that node will simply ignore this return value. Edit: Oops, you deleted the question I was responding to :)